# Zuul API Gateway Logger filter not logging requests, returns 401 instead

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a few micro-services powered by Ribbon, Eureka and OAuth2 auth server. Everything worked like a charm. Then I introduced Zuul API Gateway, and added a logger class to log my requests.

**Zuul Gateway yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-api-gateway-service
server:
  port: 8765
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://theusername:thepassword@localhost:8761/eureka
    register-with-eureka: true
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie, Authorization
  routes:
    job-service:
      path: /api/**
      url: http://localhost:7084
    jobposting-service:
       path: /api/**
       url: http://localhost:6084
       stripPrefix: false
    oauth:
      path: /auth/**
      url: http://localhost:9191
```

**Zuul Appplication class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ZuulApiGatewayServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulApiGatewayServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**LoggingFilter**

```
@Component
public class ZuulLoggingFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre"; //pre post error
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {
        HttpServletRequest request = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest();
        logger.info("request -> {} request uri -> {}", request, request.getRequestURI());
//
//        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
//        // Add a custom header in the request
//        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization",
//                request.getHeader("Authorization"));
//        logger.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(),
//                request.getRequestURL().toString()));
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then my API requests turned out not working. Any request, even with Authorization token attached to the header, returns 401 unauthorized. The logger not logging anything as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie, Authorization` means do not pass these headers. Try removing `Authorization` from that list.

Comment: {
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}

Comment: That is what I get when I remove the headers

Comment: Your saying adding a logging filter causes the error?

Comment: No, the Zuul Gateway isn't working